# Show div if data attr is same

Tags: jquery

I need your help with jQuery. How can I make with attribute that if I click on Curl button the div below with data-language curl appear, same for Java, Node and PHP please ?

Here is my HTML

```
<div class"btn-container">
  <a language-button="curl">Curl</a>
  <a language-button="java">Java</a>
  <a language-button="node">Node</a>
  <a language-button="php">PHP</a>
</div>

<div class="row description" data-language="curl">
</div>
<div class="row description" data-language="java">
</div>
<div class="row description" data-language="node">
</div>
<div class="row description" data-language="php">
</div>
```

Here is my Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     for ($o = 1; $o <= derniere_table_infos; $o++) {
       (function ($o) {
           $('.btn-container>a:nth-child(' + $o + ')').click(function () {
                $('.description').hide();
                if($(this).attr('language-button') == $('.description').attr('data-language')){
                   // Don't know what to put there and if "if condition" is good
                }           
       })($o);
     }
});
```

And I'm stuck there, I don't know how to make that if I click on the button I want to appear the good description and hide the others.
Thanks.

Comment: Your code has an error - `<div class"btn-container">` should be `<div class="btn-container">` and it looks like you also have errors in your jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straight-forward. Hide all the `div`s by default and listen to the `click` event of the `a` tags.

When click happens, get the value of the corresponding `language-button` attribute and then show only the `div` which has the correct assignment:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.row.description').hide();

  $('a[language-button]').click(function() {
    var lang = $(this).attr('language-button');
    $('.row.description').hide();
    $('.row.description[data-language=' + lang + ']').show();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class "btn-container">
  <a language-button="curl">Curl</a>
  <a language-button="java">Java</a>
  <a language-button="node">Node</a>
  <a language-button="php">PHP</a>
</div>

<div class="row description" data-language="curl">curl</div>
<div class="row description" data-language="java">java</div>
<div class="row description" data-language="node">node</div>
<div class="row description" data-language="php">php</div>
```